# How to attach "onchange" event handler to Wagtail's ChoiceBlock to update other input form

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I finally attached the "onchange" event handler to Wagtail's `ChoiceBlock` without using a widget.

The follows are the approach.

```
class CodeChoiceBlock(ChoiceBlock):
    def __init__(self, choices=None, default=None, required=True, help_text=None, **kwargs): 
        super(CodeChoiceBlock, self).__init__(choices=choices, 
                                              default=default, 
                                              required=required, 
                                              help_text=help_text, 
                                              **kwargs)
        self.field.widget.attrs.update({'onchange': 'update_mode(this)'})
```

`update_mode()` is a javascript method used to update the mode of a textarea when the value of `ChoiceBlock` is changed.

> I keep the question below

---

I am trying to attach a "onchange" event handler to Wagtail's ChoiceBlock.

The purpose is to update the codemirror's mode of a textarea.

I created a widget called `CodeSelectWidget`, which inherits `WidgetWithScript` and `widgets.Select`.

I overrided `render_js_init` method with following javascript.

```
def render_js_init(self, id_, name, value):
    jsinit = """
        code_choice_{varname!s} = document.getElementById("{id!s}").onchange(function() {{
            var code_text_area = document.getElementById("{code_id!s}");
            var code_text_editor = window.{code_editor!s};
            code_text_area.text();
            code_text_editor.setOption(
                "mode",
                {mode!s}
            );
        }})
    """
    return jsinit.fromat(varname=id_to_var_name(id_),
                         id=id_, 
                         code_id=str(id_).replace('language','code'), 
                         code_editor=find_code_editor(id_),
                         mode=codemapper[value])
```

And then I created a customized choice block called `CodeChoiceBlock`, which inherits `ChoiceBlock`.

I overrided `field` method with adding `'widget': CodeSelectWidget()` to `field_kwargs` as follow

```
def field(self):
    field_kwargs = {
        'widget': CodeSelectWidget(),
    }
    field_kwargs.update(self.field_options)
    return forms.ChoiceField(**field_kwargs)
```

However, there was nothing happened when I change the value of the choice input. And there is no any error message either.

Comment: You need to narrow down your question further: what's the *specific* step you're having problems with? For example, is it "how do I attach a function to run each time a ChoiceBlock is changed"? If so, what did you try, and how is it failing? At the moment, all your question really says is: "I tried writing some more code, and it didn't work."

Comment: @gasman Thank you very much for your advice. I will revise my question to make it more specific and concise.

Comment: Have you tried putting `alert` or `console.log` lines in your Javascript snippet to find out which bits of code are actually being reached?

Comment: @gasman sorry for responding late. Yes, I tried it to check whether this approach work or not. I also check the codes with chrome's "inspect" and "view source code". But I could not find the codes I wrote in `render_js_init` of `CodeSelectWidget`. Thank you very much

Comment: If your `render_js_init` code isn't appearing, then the next question to ask is "am I really sure that `CodeChoiceWidget` is being used at all?" But at this point I'm finished here, sorry - I can't walk you through the debugging process. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @gasman Thank you very much for the advice. I will check the link you attached. I did give lots of unnecessary information. I will try to make the question more clear and concise next. 
Back to this question, I check Django's document again. The way to use widget in ChoiceFlied is quite different from the way in CharField. But I finally can attach "onchange" event handler to Wagtail's `ChoiceBlock` without using widget. I added "onchange" attribute with a javascript method to `forms.Select`. Thank you very much.